# Vue Lifecycle: Object is undefined when binding attributes

Tags: object, vue.js, undefined, lifecycle

I seem to be having an issue with the vue lifecycle - the global objects that I'm retrieving data in the DOM using something like `{{ family.plusOne }}` is defined.

When I'm using it as an attribute such as `:checked="family.plusOne"` //expecting true as value, it's undefined.

I tried running the `:check="callFunction()"` and logging it to console.

I get two calls, one saying

> family.plusOne is undefined

and another log to console saying

> family.plusOne being true

which is the value I expected.

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" @change="setPlusOne($event.target.checked)" class="mdl-switch__input" :checked="(family.plusOne == 1)"/>
    <span class="mdl-switch__label" >{{family.plusOne == 1}}</span>
</label>
```

The `{{family.plus ==1 }}` within the span displays true but the `:checked="(family.plusOne ==1)"` is false

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are passing just family.plusOne, what is the result in the child?, undefined?

Secondly, may you can use a computed property like

:checked="computedFamilyPlusOne"

`computed: {
    computedFamilyPlusOne: {
        if(this.family.plusOne == 1){
          return true
        }else {
          return false
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Hi Ignacio!

Thank you for your response.

When I attempted to use a computed property. The strangest thing happens. It makes two calls to computedFamilyPlusOne. I know this because I put a console.log(this.family.plusOne) within the computed property. The first call prints "undefined" and the second call is "true". Therefore, in the DOM - my computed property only shows the value when plusOne is undefined. Madness!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `family` object does not exist as part of the default data binding in the `data() {}` method that is usually on a Vue.js component. That would mean that before the component is mounted, Vue doesn't know the value when it compiles the template, so it appears as though the value is undefined. Then, at some point, you are probably updating ONLY that property of the `family` object. This means that the reactive-state of the object has never changed, so Vue.js doesn't know that it needs to recompute the template ([reactive "gotcha"](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)).

To verify that I am correct, make sure that you use the `Vue.set()` method, or re-bind a new object with the updated property value for the `family` object.

Comment: Hi th3n3wguy,

In the data() method, I have the following:

  data() {
    return {
      family: {}
    };

I also have this following that :

  mounted() {
    this.populatePeople();
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  },

this.populatePeople(); function updates this.family. I am able to use the this.family objects with everything else (radio buttons, span, h2) It's just so strange with this switch.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the lifecycle phases

```
created() {
    this.populatePeople();
},
updated() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
},
```

This allowed me to update the data before the DOM was loaded and following some solutions, I call componentHandler.upgradeDom() to show the switches and radio buttons correctly.